# unable to set header background using css

Tags: html, css

I am learning Html5 and Css3. I am trying to create a layout, where I need to apply background image to the header. I think I have marked all the tags correctly but it doesn't seem to work. please help me. I don't get it where I am going wrong ?

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HOME</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header>

      </header>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

***css3***

```
body
{
    margin:0;
}
.container
{
    width: 960px;
    height: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:0 auto;
}

header
{
    height: 202px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(images/header.png);
}
```

Comment: Try some " around the image-url.

Comment: tried it. still aint working.

Comment: The path to your image might be wrong then.

Comment: checked that too. its inside the images folder. also tried putting the image inside the same path as of html file. still not working. i dont understan where i am going wrong.

Comment: I'd bet it's that you are using a relative url in your background-image. For example if your page is located at http://example.com/page/subpage then its actually trying to get to http://example.com/page/images/header.png. Try adding one or more ../ in front of that url or just use the absolute url instead to be sure that's not the problem.

Comment: The console output will tell you if the image url is wrong. Check that

Comment: This works fine.As the first comment sugested, put quotes.[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7mbLhmeL/)

Comment: T0t3sMcG0t3s, thanx a lot !! finally it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your path is incorrect or there's something wrong with its file permissions.

Note that your path should be relative to whatever folder your CSS file is in (and NOT your HTML file). **The most likely cause of your issue, is that you made your URL relative to your HTML file instead of your CSS file!**

Anyway, if I replace the URL with another image path (that I know to be correct), your code works fine :

```css
body {
    margin:0;
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:0 auto;
}

header {
    height: 202px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRsBv.png?s=328&g=1");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>

  </header>
</div>
```

---

## Note :

Some browsers may have issues if your leave out the quotes around the URL, but if you're using Chrome or Firefox, it should work regardless of whether you use quotes.

Comment: ok. so here is the main problem!! when i apply a remote path for the background image, it works. but when i give a path for an image in my pc, it doesnt work. why is that??

Comment: @VishnuprasadVenugopal : Your path should be relative to whatever folder your CSS file is in (and NOT your HTML file). If you think you did that correctly, please give me a link to your HTML file and a link to your image (assuming they're both available online). Then, I can do a quick check of what's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Check the image file name's extension.

May be the extension part is in uppercase format like "header.PNG", instead of "header.png".